# How can I migrate a Drupal site to Amazon Web Services EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, drupal-7

I have a working local Drupal 7 site (with local MySQL Database), but now I'm trying to migrate it to Amazon Web Services (which is currently running a test Drupal site successfully).  I have all of my drupal files in a directory `mydrupalsite` on the EC2 instance server and the database has been added to the remote MySQL, but I don't know what to do now in order to configure apache to show the new site.

What I have tried so far:

- I added the file in `/etc/apche2/sites-available` (copied the old instance and changed the directory name where appropriate)
- I changed the symlinks (deleted the old symlink and added a new one) in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` so that only the new file is pointed to.
- Then I rebooted the server and navigated to the site, but it's taking me to the install page (as though i were starting over)

Here are the contents of $databases variable in the settings file on my local machine (with username changed but the pw is an empty string)

```
if (!isset($databases)) {
  $databases = array();
}

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'naicdrpl',
  'username' => 'mylocalsiteusername',
  'password' => '',    //    password is an empty string
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => 33067 );
```

Comment: Is your Database Engine local or are you using RDS?

Comment: it's a local database.  but the database is also on the remote instance so that's not the problem.

Comment: Did you import "mydrupalsite.sql" to your Local Databse?

Comment: No i imported it to the remote MySQL (but it's there in MySQL along with the old db)

Comment: Can you paste what you are using in your /sites/default/settings.php just mask the credentials

Comment: Go to the webfoot of the site and run this command "crush cc all" and see if it runs successfully or gives some errors?

Comment: `drush cc all` ran successfully

Comment: Why is the port 33067?

Comment: that's just my local configuration (initially set up by acquia devdesktop).  On the remote server the port is an empty string (which is the same configuration as the existing, working drupal site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [backup&migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module for migration. It is very easy for using.

1. Zip all files from your Drupal directory. Copy/unzip that file on new server.
2. Backup your database in file with backup&migrate module.
3. Install Drupal site on new server. Run install.php and follow steps - you should probably change settings in `/sites/default/settings.php file`.
4. Go on `/admin/modules` and enable backup and migrate.
5. Go on `/admin/config/system/backup_migrate/restore` upload your backup file and click restore button

**NOTE 1 (database settings):**

For Drupal installation of course you need to have database. You should just create empty DB and set up user for that database. You should also set up password for that DB user and give him full privileges. In settings.php file you then change that data:

```
if (!isset($databases)) {
  $databases = array();
}

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'nameofyourDB', //here you enter name of new empty database
  'username' => 'mylocalsiteDBusername', //here you enter user name of database user
  'password' => 'yourpassword',    //you should always set up password for database user for security reasons
  'host' => '127.0.0.1', //name of your host (usually is localhost)
  'port' => 33067 ); //default MySql port
```

Basically here you set up Drupal site on empty database you created on new server. After that you fill that database using backup and migrate module.

**NOTE 2 (settings.php file premissions):**

When you migrate site and (in your case replace old one with new) you want to change settings.php file there can be a little problem with write permissions of the settings.php file. It is a common case that by default you can't change settings.php so in order to edit/replace that file you need to change permissions of the file and also of the folders where this file is placed. With no write permissions you can end up with new site and old settings.php file (the settings.php file from site you migrate will not overwrite old file).

Hope this helps.

Comment: After i get the backup on the new server (AWS's EC2 instance), how do i configure the server to use the new site instead of the old one?  I added the file in `/etc/apche2/sites-available` and changed the symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` so that only the new file is pointed to.  Then i rebooted the server, but it's taking me to the install page.

Comment: If you can get to the install page then your Apache config is working fine - usually the issue you're describing means settings.php is missing, or can't be read by the web server

Comment: It can be a problem sometimes when you want to change settings.php file. I will add note in my answer for that issue for people who might have that problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the GUI with the Backup and Migrate module https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Comment: Backing up and transferring is not the problem.  After i get the full backup on the new server, how do i configure apache to use the new site instead of the old one?

Comment: If you follow what @Darko said, it basically replaces the blank site you had running, with the site you made the Backup from (Using Backup and Migrate)  So you should not need to do anything with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Okay it appears the issue was that settings.php did not have the needed configuration.  Here was the solution that worked for me:

1. In order to determine what was needed, I created a temporary database in mysql call temp_db
2. I commented out the database section of settings.php
3. I navigated to the site which started the install process again
4. I went through the install process using the new temp_db
5. After completing this process, I went to settings.php and changed the db name to the correct one.
6. Went to the EC2 instance again and it worked!

Thank so much to everyone who helped!

Comment: Yes, as we assumed problem was in settings.php. I will add one more note in my answer for detailed database configuration when you migrate site using backup&migrate. Cheers