# How can I upload files to Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-ec2

I managed to configure my website on a Linux ec2 instance with Drupal. But I don't know where I need to modify the files of the server. I already have a fully functional website on my local host and would like to upload it in my ec2 instance.

Can I upload my site somewhere in Drupal? I also tried without Drupal, I installed Apache, and everything but I can't add files on /var/www/ folder because I don't have the necessary permission.

Can you please give me some suggestions or tutorials that might help me?

Comment: Why cannot you add files to var/www? You have full access to the ec2 instance right?

Comment: When i'm trying to give permissions to var/www it says that i can't do it because of the following issue : permission denied

Comment: It seems that i haven't root permissions

Comment: Can I change this fact? Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: What command you use to change permission

Answer (score 0):

You can change file permissions using terminal command.

As super user use:

```
chmod -R 777 var/www/
```

The -R makes it recursive. For security reasons it's not a good practice to give everyone access to  var/www folder. Really consider do you want your filesystem to be so accessible.

My suggestion is to make sub folder and temporary give it full access while you migrate your site from local server.

```
chmod -R 777 var/www/folder_for_your_drupal_site
```

After you done with your local site migration you should change back permissions on Drupal default settings (pay attention on settings.php file).

For further info related with migration of local Drupal site check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751524/how-can-i-migrate-a-drupal-site-to-amazon-web-services-ec2/37752053#37752053).

Hope this helps.